# How do I make a bootable usb drive for ubuntu?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

How do I make a bootable usb drive from the .iso file?  Using windows 7 on a lenovo x140e.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux Live USB Creator, never had a problem

[Link](http://www.linuxliveusb.com)

You can even setup persistence and use the drive as a portable Ubuntu (but think need legacy mode enabled on new pcs for it to see the persistence option)

Obviously, you can also choose to install with it as well.

Also with Win7 I think you can just right click iso and it gives option to write to USB (if drive plugged in)

**Edit **

If your not familiar with persistence, it basically a place that saved files and packages will go to. Without persistence anything you do on a live CD will be gone on next boot.

So you can not only use the drive to install Ubuntu, but you can also take it around with you and boot from USB if you want access to Ubuntu on a PC that don't have it installed.

**Edit2 **

If this gets you going please mark as accepted so we both get some credit and more importantly, so the next person knows it's an accepted answer for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Easy to use. Select burn to an ISO image and browse for the Ubuntu file. If it needs syslinux it will automatically download it and write to the drive. If you can't see your drive, press `ALT-F`.